# What could one do with a 4 BIT computer made out of discrete logic gates?

Tags: logic-gates, programming, display, hardware

I  want to manually program the 4 bit computer . (Without another computer). I want it to display a message  on a LCD  display. Let's say a Hd44780 display or a Nokia display. Have  a nice day.

Here is an  example that I got from the  web that  could help. (I do not OWN the image)

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: " What could one do with a 4 BIT computer made out of discrete logic gates? " I want to know if I can  use a 4 bit computer to display a message on a LCD  display.

Comment: A better title would probably be specific to that then, not what can you do with a 4-bit computer in general. You could interface them but it would probably be pretty painful, have a read of the VGA spec it's probably the simplest protocol.

Comment: jramsay42 I would like to build it from  ground up. Still learning  about how computers work though. That is why I ask questions like  this one. Just  want some  source which I could  rely on to build my own. have a nice day.

Comment: You will want to design it from the ground up, not just use a schematic you grabbed off some random person on the Internet.

Comment: @immibis I can  rely on this  schematic. Kind of. Still need  some help though.

Comment: Ask a specific question then.

Comment: @Jardel B. I know you would like to build it from the ground up, that's fine. If you want to interface with an LCD screen you will need to use a protocol such as VGA or HDMI. I highly recommend VGA

Comment: @jramsay42 A HD44780 display is fine for me. That's what you meant , Am I  right ? Thanks for  taking the time to answer.

Comment: @immibis Let's  say  controlling a robot for example.

Comment: @Jardel B. Ah okay, sorry should have checked the datasheet for the display you mentioned. Shouldn't be too bad too design a state machine for interfacing with it.

Comment: @jramsay42 What  would i  have to learn in order to do that?

Comment: @Jardel B. Are you familiar with the concept of a state machine and how to implement them in physical logic or a HDL? That's probably the most important thing in digital circuit design

Comment: @JardelB. Unfortunately "how do I control a robot?" is also very non-specific.

Comment: Use it to compute tank war-like games on mobiles with angle and pull strength to hit a target.  That's how a famous Italian Engineer centuries ago made his money propelling objects between hundreds of other inventions....or make it say Have a nice day in ASCII while playing Yankee Doodle Drump  (;) Or have a slide rule competition computing the tolerance errors of both calculators on each scale. or emulate a PDP11 with more LEDs and paddle switches.

Comment: IMHO: a 4-bit homebrew computer is not very useful or interesting, just because most of the things it can do could be done with discrete hardware in a similar amount of chips. Go for *at least* 8-bit data and 16-bit addresses, then (if you have a keyboard and screen) write some simple variant of Adventure.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That sounds interesting, although I do not play video games. Do you recall the name of this Italian you mentioned?

Comment: Leonardo Divinci

Answer (score 3):

If the 4-bit instruction set you come up with is [Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) you can do anything with the 4-bit computer you can do with a supercomputer (subject to limitations on memory, and it will tend to run a fair bit slower).

Answer (score 0):

I've used Monolithic Memories PROMs to implement controllers for testing ICs at various temperatures.

The instruction set included
1) examine one of the 5 preset temperatures (set with variable resistor) and if the front-panel switch is ON, then test at that temperature
OTHERWISE
examine the next temperature switch.
2) using an external R+C delay (likely a 555), wait for 60 seconds for the ThermoStream temp-head to stabilize at the temperature

3)send a start-pulse to the external SweptTrequency tester that evaluated the setup and hold times for some customer ECL ICs

4) restore the initial temperature to HOT (so frost is removed from the temp-head and a new IC can be placed in the test=head

5) if the 60 second delay has timed out, then do (3), else simply examine the 60 second delay once again (the system clock was only 10Hz, and the machine spent most of its  code asking "Has 60 seconds passed yet?"

**NOTICE** some of these 5 instructions are ACTIONS, and some are TEST_and_JUMP_IF_TRUE.

YOu get to define the entire instruction set. I did not need an ALU on this machine.

On another machine, that ran at 1,200 baud (because of handshaking with external data logger), there was an ADDER so as to compute some ASCII codes to insert into the output datastream.

Answer (score 0):

Invent a tiny Rx tuner that picks up 32kHz watch radiation with a very high Q BPF and CMOS inverter , so users can check their watches for accuracy then come back when the battery needs replacement and tune the Xtal trimcap to get better accuracy.

Use an ultrastable 0.1ppm external clock, and PLL with RFID coil antenna to drive the input and measure frequency error over a minute to improve resolution and detect frequency error in PPM or use the ALU to convert to minutes per month.